# Android, проблема с OnDateSetListener

Tags: eclipse, android, java, activity

```
public void DateClick(View view)
{
    OnDateSetListener myCallBack = new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yearOfYear, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {

            MainActivity.year = year;
            MainActivity.month = monthOfYear;
            MainActivity.day = dayOfMonth;
            EditText Data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
            Data.setText("");
            Data.append(Integer.toString(dayOfMonth)+"/"+Integer.toString(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+Integer.toString(year));

                        }
        };

    DatePickerDialog Change = new DatePickerDialog(this, myCallBack, 25, 7, 1993);  
    Change.show();

}
```

Сей метод прекрасно работает как на эмуляторе android 4.0.3, так и на телефоне, а на android 2.3.3 отказывается. Что может быть не так?

> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415): FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could
> not execute method of the activity
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method) 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method) 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415): Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method) 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:
> E/AndroidRuntime(415):    at
> android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
> 09-12 11:45:50.879:

Путем комментирования кусков кода, выяснил (скорее всего), что "шалит":
    DatePickerDialog Change = new DatePickerDialog(this, myCallBack, 25, 7, 1993);

Comment: Уверенны, что проблемма именно в этом методе?

Comment: Получается, что при нажатии на кнопку, описанную в activity_main.xml, регистрируется событие ClickDate, и именно после нажатия на кнопку приложение вылетает с RunTimeError. А это единственный метод, связанный с нажатием на кнопку.

Comment: Логи в студию!

Answer (score 1):

`DatePickerDialog Change = new DatePickerDialog(this, myCallBack, 25, 7, 1993);`

[Сигнатура метода](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context, android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, int, int, int)) говорит, что параметры должны быть: год, месяц, день. А не день, месяц и год. Получается как в [Записках Сумасшедшего](http://www.klassika.ru/read.html?proza/gogol/zapiski.txt&page=3) - мартобря 86-го числа :)

В Гугле тоже не боги сидят - не проверяют выход за границы видать.

**З.Ы.** Кстати, вполне повод [запостить бажочек](http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html) в исходниках Android'а